# Name me a Binary Parser. A parser for binary data

Tags: parsing, binary, protocols

So, I'm getting this data. From the network socket, or out of a file.  I'm cobbling together code that will interpret the data.  Read some bytes, check some flags, and some bytes indicate how much data follows. Read in that much data, rinse, repeat.

This task reminds me much to parsing source code.  I'm comfy with lex/yacc and antlr, but they're not up to this task.  You can't specify bits and raw bytes as tokens (well, maybe you could, but I wouldn't know how), and you can't coax them into "read two bytes, make them into an unsigned 16bit integer, call it *n*, and then read *n* bytes.".

Then again, when the spec of the protocol/data format is defined in a systematic manner (not all of them are), there should be a systematic way to read in data that is formatted according to the protocol.  Right?

There's gotta be a tool that does that.

Comment: voting to reopen because this is less about seeking recommendations and more about finding out whether or not a certain kind of technology exists. i found this page very relevant and helpful, and i hate to think it is hidden from those not having the close/reopen privilege

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may try to employ [Boost.Spirit](http://boost-spirit.com) (v2) which has recently got [binary parsing tools](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/binary.html), endianness-aware [native](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/binary/binary_native.html) and [mixed](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/quick_reference/qi_parsers/binary.html) [parsers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/binary/binary_native.html)

```
// This is not a complete and useful example, but just illustration that parsing
// of raw binary to real data components is possible
typedef boost::uint8_t byte_t;
byte_t raw[16] = { 0 };
char const* hex = "01010000005839B4C876BEF33F83C0CA";
my_custom_hex_to_bytes(hex, raw, 16);

// parse raw binary stream bytes to 4 separate words
boost::uint32_t word(0);
byte_t* beg = raw;
boost::spirit::qi::parse(beg, beg + 16, boost::spirit::qi::dword, word))
```

UPDATE: I found similar question, where Joel de Guzman confirms in his answer availability of binary parsers: [Can Boost Spirit be used to parse byte stream data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285200/can-boost-spirit-be-used-to-parse-byte-stream-data)

Comment: That looks promising.  Thank you!

Answer (score 12):

[Kaitai Struct](http://kaitai.io) initiative have emerged recently to solve exactly that task: to generate binary parsers from a spec. You can provide a scheme for serialization of arbitrary data structure in a YAML/JSON-based format like that:

```
meta:
  id: my_struct
  endian: le
seq:
  - id: some_int
    type: u4
  - id: some_string
    type: str
    encoding: UTF-8
    size: some_int + 4
  - id: another_int
    type: u4
```

compile it using `ksc` (they provide a reference compiler implementation), and, voila, you've got a parser in any supported programming language, for example, in C++:

```
my_struct_t::my_struct_t(kaitai::kstream *p_io, kaitai::kstruct *p_parent, my_struct_t *p_root) : kaitai::kstruct(p_io) {
    m__parent = p_parent;
    m__root = this;
    m_some_int = m__io->read_u4le();
    m_some_string = m__io->read_str_byte_limit((some_int() + 4), "UTF-8");
    m_another_int = m__io->read_u4le();
}
```

or in Java:

```
private void _parse() throws IOException {
    this.someInt = this._io.readU4le();
    this.someString = this._io.readStrByteLimit((someInt() + 4), "UTF-8");
    this.anotherInt = this._io.readU4le();
}
```

After adding that to your project, it provides a very intuitive API like that (an example in Java, but they support more languages):

```
// given file.dat contains 01 00 00 00|41 42 43 44|07 01 00 00

MyStruct s = MyStruct.fromFile("path/to/file.dat");
s.someString() // => "ABCD"
s.anotherInt() // => 263 = 0x107
```

It supports different endianness, conditional structures, substructures, etc, and lots more. Pretty complex data structures, such as [PNG image file format](https://github.com/kaitai-io/kaitai_struct_formats/blob/master/image/png.ksy) or [PE executable](https://github.com/kaitai-io/kaitai_struct_formats/blob/master/executable/microsoft_pe.ksy) can be parsed.

Answer (score 3):

The [Construct](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/construct) parser, written in Python, has done some interesting work in this field.

The project has had a number of authors, and periods of stagnation, but as of 2017 it seems to be more active again.

Comment: Looks like someone picked up maintenance recently. They have [new docs](http://construct.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) up too.

Answer (score 1):

Read up on ASN.1. If you can describe the binary data in its terms, you can then use various available kits. Not for the faint of heart.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/lonelybug/ddprotocol/wiki/Getting-Start

hope this is helpful to you.

Comment: Lone link is bad, please provide a summary.

Comment: sorry about that. please forgot this link, I am going to refactor this tool somehow.

Answer (score 0):

There is certainly nothing stopping you from writing a recursive decent parser, say, for binary data the same way you would hand-tool a text parser. If the format you need to read is not too complicated this is a reasonable way to proceed.

Of course, if you format is *very* simple you could take a look at [Reading binary file defined by a struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/868530/reading-binary-file-defined-by-a-struct) and similar question.

I don't know of any parser generators for non-text input, though those are also possible.

---

In the event that you are not familiar with coding parsers by hand, the canonical SO question is [Learning to write a compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669/learning-to-write-a-compiler). The [Crenshaw tutorial](http://compilers.iecc.com/crenshaw/) (and [in PDF](http://www.stack.nl/~marcov/compiler.pdf)) is a fast read.

Comment: Well, I *am* essentially writing a parser that way. By hand, that is. But am I the first person on earth to do this?

Answer (score 0):

See also google protocol buffers.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool called binpac that does exactly this.

http://www.icsi.berkeley.edu/pubs/networking/binpacIMC06.pdf