# specification driven packet format parsing?

Tags: java, python, networking

this could a shot in the dark: we have a wire packet format which is in design and in flux. Is there a flexible way to specify and parse the incoming stream instead of harding coding it?  Preferably language agnostic ... but not necessarily so. If there is a good reason not to do that, please enlighten me as well.

Thanks

Oliver

Comment: To avoid assuming: do you *need* a custom wire packet format?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Name me a Binary Parser. A parser for binary data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214863/name-me-a-binary-parser-a-parser-for-binary-data)

Comment: @Inerdial: team decision, it is too late to go back to the drawing board now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a wonderful Python library called [Construct](http://construct.wikispaces.com/). This is by far the easiest way to get started quickly.

If it is more important to be language agnostic, you can limit your wire protocol to [ASN.1 BER](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Encoding_Rules), since it's usually possible to find an encoder/decoder library for these in whatever language. For example, there's [CoDec](http://codec.sourceforge.net/) in Java and [PyASN1](http://pyasn1.sourceforge.net/) in Python. Warning: though powerful, ASN is laden with design-by-committee standardese and it's very hard to get started in it. [This site will help.](http://lionet.info/asn1c/blog/)

There are also newer, lighter ASN.1-like approaches like [Apache Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/) and [Google Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/).

Answer (score 1):

Google's [Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/) lets you specify what you want to send, then it generates the parsing and serializing code for you.

[Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/) is similar, but provides a IPC framework as well. It integrates the parsing and sockets stuff into one package.

I haven't used these libraries much, but both of them are well documented, language agnostic and are released under a permissive license – I'm sure at least one of them would suit your application.

Answer (score 1):

[Erlang](http://bravenewmethod.wordpress.com/2011/02/22/socket-binary-data-stream-parsing-in-erlang/) and Haskell both have excellent binary pattern matching.  But for your purposes (given that you are on the JVM) why not [write the connector in Scala](http://unintentionalobjectretention.blogspot.com/2009/01/erlang-style-binary-matching-in-scala.html)?